# Why not "Ende des Februars" instead of "Ende Februar"?

Tags: genitive

Can someone please explain, what's happening to genitive in following sentence?

> Ich glaube so ungefähr Ende Februar.

Comment: Short answer: They’re both valid. I don’t feel like writing the long answer, though.

Comment: No one would actually say "Ende des Februars", though.

Comment: How about "Ende Februars" Is it common in speech, if correct at all?

Comment: Note, that unspecific nouns in phrases like *Ende des Monats*, *Anfang der Woche*, *Mitte des Jahres* work exactly like you expect. I assume, it is related to the specific name used, similar to *Mittwoch früh*. Names frequently occur without any article, but I could not find the related rule quickly.

Comment: another guestion, is it still in genetive:Ende Februar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use "Ende Februar" because you're referring to a point in time. That point of time only supports and specifies a statement, it's not the subject of that statement.

> Ich glaube die Klausuren beginnen so ungefähr Ende Februar.

If you wanted to make a statement about the end of the month February (that actual portion of the month), you would use the Genitive.

> Das Ende des Dezembers ist gewöhnlich eine von vielen Festen und Feiertagen geprägte Zeit.

Comment: +1, but even Germans do the second one wrong all the time.

Comment: I am not sure if this is right. I wouldn't say the second sentence because it sounds strange.

Comment: Many things sounds strange because nobody talks in that way, I agree. The purpose of that sentence was only to showcase the grammar.

Comment: I had another question that is this expression still in genetive:Ende Februar?